# Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Data too long for column 'Data' at row 1

Tags: mysql, datatypes

When I try to enter some very long data, (response from ChatGPT API) it doesn't get saved into sessions data which Im handling manually by storing in a MySQL table.

```
$_SESSION[$propertyName."-".$ID] = addslashes($propertyValue);
```

```
Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Data too long for column 'Data' at row 1
```

Data is of Type text latin1_swedish_ci

I thought type of text can handle large amounts of data.

Comment: What is `Data` column datatype precisely? What is the length of the data to be stored in this column?

Comment: The `TEXT` data type can handle string data that is somewhat long, but not unlimited. The limit for that data type is 64KB (i.e. a string whose length can be encoded in 16 bits). If your ChatGPT response is longer than that, it won't fit in a `TEXT` column.

Comment: I changed it to LONGTEXT - it seems to be okay now.